# Java Reactor RabbitMQ Spring Boot How do I capture and return a Connection refused Exception

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am using reactive RabbitMQ, within a Spring Boot app.

I have a "Mono ServerResponse  createImage" method, which calls a Mono Image  createImage(Mono ImageDTO dto) method.

I would like to make my code better at handling errors, and ensure that exceptions within the "Mono createImage(Mono dto)" method are caught. These would then be returned as a Mono ServerResponse.

For example if RabbitMQ is not running, I get the following ConnectException:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

But the Mono ServerResponse  is a 201.

Can someone please tell me how I change my code so if I (for example) get a ConnectException (because RabbitMQ is not running), I can return a ServerResponse with a HTTP 500 code.

I have been trying all sorts of onErrorResume, onErrorMap, but no luck.

Here is the code:

```java
public Mono<ServerResponse> createImage(ServerRequest request) {
    var dto = request.bodyToMono(ImageDTO.class);

    return service.createImage(dto)
            .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(s))
            .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.just("Error " + e.getMessage())
            .flatMap(s -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .bodyValue(s)));
}
```

This is the createImage method:

```java
public Mono<Image> createImage(Mono<ImageDTO> dto) {
    return dto.flatMap(imageDto -> {
        var image = mapperImageDTOToEntity(imageDto);
        var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json;
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(image);
            var imageSerialized = SerializationUtils.serialize(json);
            /*
                * Simple rabbit queue implementation
                * Replace with Topic exchange
                */
            var outbound = Flux.just( new OutboundMessage(
                    "",
                    QUEUE, imageSerialized));

            sender.declareQueue(QueueSpecification.queue(QUEUE))
                    .thenMany(sender.sendWithPublishConfirms(outbound))
                    .doOnError(e -> logger.error("Send failed", e))
                    .subscribe(m -> {  // blocking - but need debug
                        // println for debug
                        System.out.println("Message sent");
                        logger.debug("Message sent");
                    });
        } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe) {
            logger.warn("JSON processing exception: {}", jpe.toString());
        }

        //Return posted object to the client.
        return Mono.just(image);
    });
}
```